# How to create line chart in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, graph, linegraph

I am creating a budget application in iPhone, to budget for personal incomes and expenses.

Client's need is

- I want to see line graph (like stock market line report).
- Red line for (monthly / weekly / daily) expenses
- Green line for (monthly / weekly / daily) incomes

The question is how? Till now, I have never faced this kind of requirement. Can you please some offer some guidance regarding creating line chart in iPhone?

Comment: You should probably start googling before you come here ;)

Comment: I also want to integrate line chart in my app.What about Sencha touch ?? can we integrate in my app ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should try [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).

Comment: For examples of the kind of line charts that Core Plot can generate, see this page on the project wiki: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/PlotExamples

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the solution for it.

If you want to use graphs in your application, there are two options for you.

```
* Core Plot - http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/
* s7GraphView - http://code.google.com/p/s7graphview/
```

I found that s7graphview is more preferable to iPhone application & Core-Plot is more suitable to MAC OSx development.

I have downloaded both of them & started R & D on implementing it on application.

But Core-plot provides different kinds of facility & advance features while s7graphview is very limited.

Let me explain, how to install core plot,

First Go to this site,

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

You will see a command there(as given below) but you will not be able to execute it in your mac os terminal.

( hg clone https://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/ core-plot )

Because it requires following things

- Mercurial
- Terminal Settings

Step 1 ) Let me explain terminal settings. Open Terminal & execute following commands

- export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
- export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Step 2 ) Download & setup mercurial from following link.

- http://mercurial.berkwood.com/

Step 3 ) Now open /Users/User-Name/core-plot/Examples

- You will find samples here.

You may also continue a tutorial given here.

- http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application

this link may be helpful.

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications

Comment: MacPorts and Fink are not required for Core Plot development or usage, just a version of Mercurial. You can get Mercurial from the developer's website: http://mercurial.selenic.com/.

Comment: Python is included with OS X; there's no need to download/install it.